# how to handle external links in HTML component in adobe Air?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, flex3

I have an AIR Project which has a HTML component. This HTML component Load a URL. Once specified page is loaded, there are some links on the page that need to be open in separate HTML tabs. 
My problem is when I click any of these link nothing happens. how can I resolve this issue. I created the HTML component as:

```
<mx:HTML id="htmlPage" left="0" top="35" right="0" bottom="0" 
    contentBackgroundColor="#1B1B1B"
    paintsDefaultBackground="true"
    location="page URL"        
    />
```

Comment: show some AS3 code. What you have tried in AS3?

Comment: the website is a flex web application. I use its swf file that is loaded in the HTML control. This swf file contains external link to a html page which is in the same directory as of swf. In flash web App it simply call navigate to url when user click on that link. In web browser it opens html file in separate tab. but here in Air HTML control it does nothing.

Comment: By me it does not work as well

Comment: You can try to navigate to your external page with the help of javascript as workaround.

Comment: we can open new link in system browser by setting "htmlLoader.navigateInSystemBrowser = true". but it will open system default web browser. I am looking for something, which I can use to open new link in new tab but inside Air application.

Answer (score 1):

```
htmlPage.htmlLoader.navigateInSystemBrowser = true
```

Comment: this will open system default web browser. I have a download link in html control. how can I start downloading without opening system default browser.

Comment: No you can;t download any content on user;s machine without his/her concern.

Comment: It is not something that is being done without user concern. Here user is seeing a list of file. he/she wants to download a file. my question is how can we know in Air application that which link user want to open or which file user want to download?

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of your GUI because it is really difficult to understand the exact problem without GUI, the image which is comming in my mind is that you have a list where a bunch of checkbox representing files and you need to select checkbox, then there must be a btn which will start download. Please let me know if this is the case.

Comment: I used a different approach to solve this problem. I use process communication mechanism to communicate the flash application with the Air application. I send the external URLs to Air application through local connection and then in Air application I handled them manually.